# Get transparent color to create specific color on a specific background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, transparency, color-reproduction

I've got some Images like this one:
[image]

Now I need to find out the color which will become the orange in the right center of the image when drawn on a new layer with 50% opacity (The Background is the grey color).

Sadly I've no idea how to do this.

Comment: You want to place that orange area into a new layer on top of the grey area, set 50% opacity for the orange area and then figure out what the color would be in that area?

Comment: Well I've spent a long time guessing for the exact color. I think that there should be a method in PS providing such a feature.

Comment: Here's an Action I made in PS cs3. You'll need to select two colors you want to blend as your foreground and background colors and then play the action. - It takes those colors and blends them into one color cube and tries to paste it in to your currently open document. https://www.dropbox.com/s/o77b3yrr4dl2nli/ColorBLEND.atn

Comment: @joonas: I think you have missed the point of the question. The OP wants to find out what the overlay color `is`. He/she does not know.

Comment: @tokk: is the underlying color always grey (the same value for R,G, & B)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

1. Open the image editor. Create a layer behind the transparent image.
2. Set the background color of the layer you created to #000000 or rgb(0,0,0)
3. Get the color code of your transparent image as hexadecimal number.
4. Convert hexadecimal to decimal. Multiply it by 2. Convert the result to hexadecimal.

I tried this with two colors. I think Photoshop uses transparent tool with a polynomial function, not a linear function. Probably because of that, first test gave me a result accuracy of 96%. Second test gave 99% accuracy. I hope it helps.